# How can I change toValue/fromValue of CABasicAnimation while the animation is on

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to change the values of toValue/fromValue of CABasicAnimation where the animation is `heartBeatAnimation`

```
let heartBeatAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
heartBeatAnimation.duration       = 0.75
heartBeatAnimation.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
heartBeatAnimation.autoreverses   = true
heartBeatAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
heartBeatAnimation.toValue        = 1.15
```

while the animation is on, where I get the current value of the `transform.scale` during the animation with this :

```
let currentValue = someView.layer.presentation()?.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale")
heartBeatAnimation.fromValue = currentValue
heartBeatAnimation.toValue   = currentValue
```

after I changed the values, the `heartBeatAnimation` won't change its `toValue/fromValue` till I remove animation then add once again !

Is there any way to make these changes in realtime while the animation on ?!

Comment: You mea  getting the scale will stop the animation?

Comment: after I change the values the `heartBeatAnimation` won't change its `toValue/fromValue` till I remove animation then add once again !

Comment: And is adding the animation directly after it breaking thr animation?

Comment: yes, any updates to `toValue/fromValue` will took a place after re-adding the animation !

Comment: @MohammadEliassAlhusain can you please review my answer if you get time?

Comment: @agibson007 Sorry, for being late, work and solving hard problems, btw thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it appear in real time by updating the model layers current scale to the presentation layers scale and then readding the animation with an update to the beginTime property so that the animation appears to never have stopped. Here is an example.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var scale : CGFloat = 1.2

    var shapeLayer : CAShapeLayer!
    var button : UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //add a shapelayer
        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/4, height: self.view.bounds.width/4)
        shapeLayer.position = self.view.center
        shapeLayer.path = drawStarPath(frame: shapeLayer.bounds).cgPath
        let color = UIColor(red: 0.989, green: 1.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.000)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)


        //button for action
        button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 50))
        button.center = self.view.center
        button.center.y = self.view.bounds.height - 70
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Animate", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)

        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }

@objc func pressed(sender:UIButton) {

     var isInterupted = false

        if let presentation = shapeLayer.presentation(){
            if let animScale = presentation.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale.xy"){
                if let value = animScale as? CGFloat{
                    //set current animation spot
                    shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, value, value, 1)
                    shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
                    scale += 0.2
                    isInterupted = true
                    print("The current toValue is \(scale)")

                }
            }
        }


        button.setTitle("Animating...", for: .normal)

        let heartBeatAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
        heartBeatAnimation.duration       = 0.5
        let beginTimeNeeded = (1/scale) * CGFloat(heartBeatAnimation.duration)
        heartBeatAnimation.repeatCount    = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        heartBeatAnimation.autoreverses   = true
        heartBeatAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
        heartBeatAnimation.toValue        = scale
        if isInterupted == true{
            heartBeatAnimation.beginTime = CFTimeInterval(beginTimeNeeded)
        }
        heartBeatAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        shapeLayer.add(heartBeatAnimation, forKey: "beatAnimation")
    }

    func drawStarPath(frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 140, height: 140)) ->UIBezierPath{
        //// Star Drawing
        let starPath = UIBezierPath()
        starPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.50000 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.21071 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.60202 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.35958 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.77513 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.41061 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.66508 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.55364 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.67004 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.73404 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.50000 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.67357 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.32996 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.73404 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.33492 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.55364 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.22487 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.41061 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.39798 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.35958 * frame.height))
        return starPath
    }

}
```

I am pressing the button to add more scale to the animation.
Here is the result:
[image: Result]